# can't get Kindle fire google Map and GPS location

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, kindle-fire

There are two thing which I need to find answer. Can anyone tell me?

1. Can we find GPS location of device by any chance in new Kindle fire. As I searched that couple of days back ...client is guessing that GPS is supported now.. so currently kindle fire support GPS?
2. Google maps integration is allowed or we need to use alternative maps like Open street map etc.

Comment: Client is guessing wrongly then. A quick Google for "kindle fire" + "gps" would have told you that.

Comment: can you help me for how we can open street map integrate in kindle fire?

Answer (score 0):

```
see below link 
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android
```

Comment: Hello friend,thanks for rpl. but i want to use map for kindle fire not for android mobile. so please if you have any idea related to that than help me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.